# Shortest code that return SIGSEGV among the given languages

Tags: code-golf, c, c++, assembly

I come across a question in a coding competion

"write  a code that returns SIGSEGV(Segmentation fault )   " .

Points were given on the basis of length of code.
The prgramming languages available  were asm,c,c++,java .

I knew c language better  and submitted my code as

```
   main(){char *c="h";c[3]='j';}
```

But others solve it in shorter length  than me .  How it is possible ?  Can any one explain plz.

Platform UBUNTU 10.04

Comment: `int main() { std::cout << "SIGSEGV(Segmentation fault )" << std::endl; }`

Comment: but this is not shorter than above code!!

Comment: `movl $0,0` (GNU AS syntax, x86_64 - the _modern_ assembly segfault)

Comment: The question really can't be answered without reference to a specific platform. There is, for example, no C code that is guaranteed to give a SIGSEGV on every platform.

Comment: Hilarious, @sehe!

Comment: 14 characters: `main(){*""=0;}`

Comment: @DietrichEpp, I'm afraid compiler may object without casting off const.

Comment: @sehe: That'd be both faster and shorter if you would do `std::cout << "SIGSEGV(Segmentation fault )\n";` instead. :-)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: Not in traditional C mode, with warnings turned off.

Comment: This is a question that has an answer. There is a shortest program that produces the desired result. I don't agree that it should've been closed.

Comment: I'd be pretty interested in **ANY** java (excluding JNI/A since that'd be C again) code that produces a sigsev ;)

Comment: This is a "make a list" question, and that is "not constructive" writ large.

Comment: @dmckee There's also an "explain it" component, which is perhaps somewhat redeeming.

Comment: The folks at nntp:comp.lang.c would have everyone know that using any declaration for `main` other that `int main(void)`, `void main(void)`, or `int main(int,char**)` is "implementation-defined", and therefore no longer *standard* C.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

bending the rules a bit ; the C linker doesn't care if 'main' is a function or not :

```
int main=0;
```

indeed, the default type is 'int' and the default global initialiser is 0 :

```
main;
```

Comment: That's pretty darn short. +1 And it compiles (though with a warning)

Comment: +1: Though, if it were my question, that would be bending the rules too far for me to accept as an answer. But that's still really impressive, and likely about the shortest you can go.

Answer (score 6):

In C, something like this is fairly short:

```
int main(void)
{
  return *(int *)0=1;
}
```

...or for a less proper version with minimal whitespace:

```
main(){*(int*)0=1;}
```

---

...even less proper, but shorter (the source code, at least):

```
main(){puts(0);}
```

It calls `puts()` with an implicit prototype, but still "works" if linked with the standard library.

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways to make a program return SIGSEGV. One of these is via segmentation fault due to stack overflow of a recursive function calling itself a lot of times. In C, a short (if not the shortest) code for this would be:

```
main(){main();}
```

Comment: is there any shorter code than this in other language..?

Comment: In java, even the 'public static void main' is larger than this. Probably there's a shorter solution in asm, but I'm not really sure about it...

Answer (score 3):

Besides may other ways of suicide as demonstrated by others, your way could be expressed a bit shorter as

```
main(){++*((int*)"");}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Assembly, 3 characters

```
RET
```

### C, 5 characters

```
main;
```

Answer (score 2):

Nah, as short as this :

```
int main;
```

Comment: As the accepted answer shows, you don't even need the `int `.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 18 characters

I know this wasn't requested, but have a Ruby one, because why not. :D

```
Process.kill 11,$$
```